# Alternative to Year function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, ms-access

I have been using the SQL query below in Access, which previosuly worked until I moved my data to Oracle :-

```
SELECT Count(*) AS xCount
FROM tblQuotesNew AS t1
WHERE (((t1.sales_route)='Sales Mailbox') AND ((t1.DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS)=Year(Date())));
```

This now produces an inconsistent datatypes error is Access.

How should I adjust my query so that it will execute in Access?

Comment: In Oracle you can get current year in several different ways, such as `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` but, what's the exact relationship between Access and Oracle? Do you need a cross-DMBS query or you're linking both programs in some way?

Comment: I'm using Access as a front end only. All the data is held in Oracle. The query above restricts to just the current year.

Comment: So `DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS` is a really a year, not a date?

Comment: @Gustav "DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS" the field is a date. In the context of the Where clause, I'm returning everything where DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS is in the current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal query (not a pass-through) in Access:

```
SELECT 
    Count(*) AS xCount
FROM 
    tblQuotesNew AS t1
WHERE 
    t1.sales_route='Sales Mailbox'
    AND 
    (t1.DATE_SENT_TO_REGISTRATIONS Between
        DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 1) And
        DateSerial(Year(Date()), 12, 31));
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.